# How to gracefully upgrade production rethinkdb server

Tags: rethinkdb

We have host a rethinkdb cluster with millions of docs in production.

Every time we try to upgrade rethinkdb, we had to rebuild index, which will cause the table almost unavailable (Read very slow, and not writable) for hours or even days during upgrading.

So How do you guys upgrade rethinkdb in production ?

Comment: Which was the last version you migrated indexes on? RethinkDB 2.2 significantly improved the index construction (and migration) process to have less impact on production load.
Also note that it's not necessary to migrate indexes right away. Old indexes will keep working. We recommend to eventually migrate indexes, but you can usually skip a few versions before you actually need to do so.
We also made the detection of outdated indexes more granular in RethinkDB 2.3. Most indexes no longer need to be migrated at all.

Comment: @DanielMewes Thanks for reply. Currently we are running 2.2, which was upgraded from `2.0.x`, Can I upgrade it without slow reading ?

Comment: Hmm 2.2 should already have had the new index construction (and migration) code. You might want to open a GitHub issue with some details on data set size, types of indexes, hardware configuration etc.
That aside, if you only use indexes on individual fields, or "simple" compound indexes (combinations of fields) and no more complex index functions, 2.3 will probably not prompt you to migrate indexes when coming from 2.2.